# Adding And Removing Class on Active Accordion Toggle Element

Tags: jquery, accordion, slidetoggle

I have a Jquery Code for accordion and it's working well except I need to add/remove class on active trigger. What I mean is, when the H2 element is clicked, I need a class "accordion-toggled" added to it. The code shown here adds the class to all H2 elements when toggled and I only need it added to active H2.

I could use some help on this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.accordion-content> p').hide();  
   $('div.accordion-content> h2').click(function() {
     $(this).next('p').slideToggle('fast')
     .siblings('p:visible').slideUp('fast');
     $('div.accordion-content> h2').toggleClass('accordion-toggled');
   });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="accordion-content">
   <h2>Question 1</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 1</p>
   <h2>Question 2</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 2</p>
   <h2>Question 3</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context) keyword you can reference the element you just clicked:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('div.accordion-content> p').hide();  
   $('div.accordion-content> h2').click(function() {
     $(this).next('p').slideToggle('fast')
     .siblings('p:visible').slideUp('fast');
      $(this).toggleClass('accordion-toggled');
      $('div.accordion-content> h2').not(this).removeClass('accordion-toggled');
   });
});
```

```css
.accordion-toggled{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion-content">
   <h2>Question 1</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 1</p>
   <h2>Question 2</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 2</p>
   <h2>Question 3</h2>
   <p>Some answers for question 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It's close enough to what I want. But if you run the code you provided, you'll notice that clicking any of the H2 element will add a class and style (red color) but click it again doesn't remove that class.

Which means it hides the answer (toggle up) but the red color of that h2 element remains. It should add and remove class based on click.

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: @Delinx you are right, changed the order of the class handling and excluded the current element from the `removeClass` selector